# Spring autowiring with bean scope of prototype

Tags: spring

I have a question in spring with autowire with a bean which is having a scope of prototype..
So basically i am writing a code which is spring with JPA.So i am autowiring my entity manager in my DAO layer .I am loading the entitymanager from a class by using the @configuraion Annotation .

```
@Configuration
public class DALConfigurationLoader {


    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
}
```

When i do this i am expecting that for every request it should get a new bean .

```
@Component
public class OfferPriceDomainDAOImpl  {



    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
        public OfferPrice getOfferPrice(String offer_Price_Id) throws DataAccessException{
           //use entitymanager here 
        }

   }
```

In this case it is a single entity manager for all the request which is wrong.i want each method should get a new entity manager .As based on the jpa specification every new request should process a new entity manager...How can i autowire a bean with a scope of prototype..

I would really appreciate if some one can answer my question..

Thank,
Swati

Answer (score 2):

Use [`@PersistenceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) to inject an EntityManager, not `@Autowired`, as outlined in the [JPA section of the Spring reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-straight). It takes care of the lifecycle for you properly.

As to why it wasn't working the way you thought it might: whenever an instance of your DAO is created, it would be injected with an EntityManager. Since the EntityManager is scope=prototype, a new one will be created for each DAO that needs to be injected for one. However, since your DAO is a singleton, only one of them is created, so only one EntityManager is ever needed.

Comment: i can not use @PersistenceContet as the way we create entity manager i different .This is the rule we kind of follow in my company ...The Dbonfigloader is some thing where we load the entity manager and autowire it to dao layer....DAO lyer object is autowired in bizz layer...so singelton object of dao is created..i want only one object of dao which should have multiple entity manager ...

Comment: So basically how many ever times i call a method on dao (which is singelton ) that many times the entity manager has to be created ..this is my goal...

Comment: If you only "kind of" follow the rule, then I suggest this is the time to break it. This is the exact problem that `@PersistenceContext` exists to solve, and it does it extremely well and with minimal effort. Otherwise, as far as I know, it's completely up to you to manage the EntityManager lifecycle. The hard way of doing it is to inject your DAO with an EntityManager factory and then open/close an EntityManager for every method call. I don't know how that will work with Spring's transaction management, if you're using that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Inject // or @Autowire
Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider;
```

and then get EntityManager instance using entityManagerProvider.get().

I used `javax.inject.Inject` instead of `Autowire` because `Provider` is defined there too. Also that also would work in Guice.